# How to get the path of a library from its handle (macOS / iOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, handle, dylib

I have a handle to a dynamic library (from using `dlopen()`). Regardless of why, I don't have access to what the path supplied to `dlopen()` was, but need the path for another function. Thus, I need to be able to acquire the path to the library using its handle.

I've tried using `dladdr()`, as I have in other parts of my app, but on macOS / iOS you aren't able to use it to find the path of a library using the handle to the library it only works with a handle to a symbol in the library. I could try adding a "locator symbol" to the library, and accomplish things this way, but I'd prefer not to.

I also tried `dlinfo()` with `RTLD_DI_LINKMAP`, but this is apparently not available on macOS / iOS.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised at how little information there is out there for this. Many of the solutions out there were not available on macOS / iOS. Others still, were only about getting the path of the *current* executable, and had nothing to do with the handle.

After a TON of searching, I finally came across some resources saying to iterate through all the loaded images using `_dyld_image_count()` and `_dyld_get_image_name()`. I initially decided against this, as it just didn't seem like an unreasonably slow way of doing things.

Eventually, I decided to go with iterating over all the loaded images, as it was the only actual solution I had come across. I googled for examples, and couldn't find any tutorials on the topic. However, I did come across an open source C++ library that implemented the functionality (found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/dll/detail/posix/path_from_handle.hpp)).

I translated it to normal C, and got rid of some excess things (such as stripping the handle). During the testing process, I noticed that the library I wanted was always last in the list (my best guess is that it stores them in the order they were loaded, and since mine isn't a system library, it will be one of the last ones loaded). This guaranteed a slow performance (in reference to the computer - to a human it'd still be nearly instantaneous). So, I did a clever optimization that started the search at the *end* of the list, rather than the beginning.

This is the final code for my solution:

```
// NOT a thread safe way of doing things
NSString *pathFromHandle(void* handle)
{
    // Since we know the image we want will always be near the end of the list, start there and go backwards
    for (uint32_t i = (_dyld_image_count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        const char* image_name = _dyld_get_image_name(i);

        // Why dlopen doesn't effect _dyld stuff: if an image is already loaded, it returns the existing handle.
        void* probe_handle = dlopen(image_name, RTLD_LAZY);
        dlclose(probe_handle);

        if (handle == probe_handle)
        {
            return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:image_name];
        }
    }


    return NULL;
}
```

It's important to note that this solution is not thread safe, as `_dyld_image_count()` and `_dyld_get_image_name()` are inherently not thread safe. This means that any other thread could load / unload an image and have a negative impact on our search.

Additionally, the [resource](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/dll/detail/posix/path_from_handle.hpp) I used questioned why `dlopen` didn't have an effect on `_dyld_image_count()`. This is because if an image is already loaded, `dlopen` does not load a new instance of the image, but rather returns the existing handle for it.

Comment: Clever hack ;) I still find very weird how many macOS/iOS corners have little (to none) documentation at all. Browsing Apple docs these days you get a feel many articles are deprecated, abandoned, etc.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah, it's definitely a pain that some of the deeper system stuff typically can't even be found in Apple's documentation site. Though there is some allure to reading through the open source headers, when you're pressed for time, you can't afford to waste it reading obscure comments.

Comment: Thanks for this! I used this loop to print out all libraries, and most were printed that they are in `/usr/lib` e.g. `/usr/lib/libssl.46.dylib`. However none of these files exist, any idea where are these libraries? I can't find them with `find /`.

Comment: That's a fair question! It's possible Apple changed how libraries are actually stored - I would have to do some research / experimenting. I assume you're working on macOS?

Comment: I'm on Macos 12 (Monterey). I was trying to make ruby work, but at the end i just had to symlink the libssl.*.dylib used by ruby into `/usr/local/lib`. Similar to how i had to fix ruby in earlier macos versions. The `/usr/local/lib` folder did not exist which is why i freaked out a bit, so i had to create that with `sudo`.

Comment: Also the `i` variable in your loop has `uint32_t` type which cannot be negative, but you use `i >= 0` condition, so basically the loop never ends if the handle was not found for some reason.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out then? If so, great! Also yes that's a very good catch, thank your for that!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve my problem, yes. I installed openssl via a package manager (brew or asdf) and then linked those into the `/usr/local/lib` folder. After this your code finds the symlinked openssl.dylib (and so as ruby). So i still don't know where's the original openssl library, but ruby works now.